# why the name capture group does not capture the same value?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

```
^(?'a'1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(?&a)$
```

im learning regex and came across this problem where it does not capture
`255.255` but `255.25`

what's wrong with my regex ?

it works if I reuse the same pattern

```
^(?:1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(?:1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

but it does not work when i try to use the name capture group `(?&a)`

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: its a PCRE(php) regex

Comment: How do you test it? It works with perl and in Notepad++. But it doesn't work with php or in regex101.

Comment: im testing it on regex101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the PCRE version. From [PCRE news](http://pcre.org/news.txt) 10.30:

> The new implementation allows backtracking into recursive group calls
>   in patterns, making it more compatible with Perl, and also fixes some
>   other previously hard-to-do issues.

- Before PCRE v10.30: Originally, a recursive group call was atomic by default.

  The order of your alternation is the pitfall because the first successful alternative wins. In your case `1?[0-9]?[0-9]` matches 25 (other alternatives are never tested), then when the regex engine tries `$` and fails, backtracking isn't possible in the group.
  You can solve the problem writing your named capture like that:

  ```
  (?<a>1[0-9]{0,2}|[3-9][0-9]?|2(?:[0-4][0-9]?|5[0-5]?|[6-9])?|0)
  ```

  *it's a bit longer but each number follows a unique path to succeed: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/e5atIy/1)*
- Since PCRE 10.30: In newer PCRE version, recursive group calls are no more atomic (backtracking is possible, as in Perl) and your pattern works as it: https://3v4l.org/HUICY

Note that actually, regex101 and PHP < 7.3 use older PCRE versions in which recursive group calls are always atomic.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, it seems the subroutine is checked atomically.
Basically, the `255.` part matches normally (although you should replace `.` with `\.` to explicitly capture a dot and not any character), but matching `255` with the `a` group matches `25` on the first possibility (the `1?[0-9]?[0-9]`), but the `$` fails and it backtracks through the entire subroutine instead of trying the other possibilities.
A solution would be rearranging your possibilities to put the `25[0-5]` first.

The pattern

```
^(?'a'25[0-5]|1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9])\.(?&a)$
```

works for me.

Comment: i tried your solution but then it wont capture 200-249 after I moved 2[0-4][0-9] to the back

Comment: Ah, then the subroutine only considers the first possibility. That's odd, but nothing you can do here. Try `^(?'a'2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]|1?[0-9]?[0-9]))\.(?&a)$` maybe?

Comment: I'll put it simply; your `1?[0-9]?[0-9]` is annoying. Break it all down to `^(?'a'1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.(?&a)$` and you'll have it working. That issue seems to be between the subroutine and alternation management in your engine. Nvm, Casimir's solution is better.